# How To Call a Method in Struts with javascript?

Tags: javascript, struts

I want to call a method in the action file from a java script
so this is the code that i have

```
<img src="image/travel.jpg" alt="test" onclick="javascript:doABC();"/>
```

and the javascript part is :

```
<script language="javascript">

function doABC(){
    var form = document.forms["Welcome"];
    form.action = "Welcome.action";
    form.submit();
}

</script>
```

like this I can call the execute method! but I have different methods that I want to call them for example I want to call test() instead of execute!!
but I dont know how to include this! 
I can handel calling different methods with buttons like this :

```
<s:submit method="execute" value="Enter The Site" align="center"/>  
<s:submit method="test" value="Enter The Site" align="center"/>
```

what should I do if I want to call test() through the onclick of the image?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "call a method", and what you want to do with the results of that call.

If you want to use an image as a link, you can use action mappings with their `"method"` attribute set to the appropriate method.

If you enable [dynamic method invocation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-DynamicMethodInvocation), you can append the method name to the URL by using `"!test"`. This is also handled by the `<s:url>` tag via its `"method"` attribute.

If you don't want to reresh the page, then you need to use Ajax, e.g., the jQuery plugin, the Dojo plugin (long-deprecated), or by using a JavaScript framework "natively", i.e., by writing plain old JavaScript.

Comment: no I have to methods in my action class of struts! I want to create different pictures and by clicking on each of them different actions would happen! I know how to work with urls I'm asking about javascript

Comment: @KhashayarNapster As I said, if you don't want to refresh the page, you need to use Ajax. If you're just trying to update an img tag's "src" attribute you can use an action URL and stream the image back. Still not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I actually dont care about refreshing or not! I have one execute method in strut that creates some data from db and send it to the next page. and also a test method that creates other data with making different query ! just think that I want to call different methods in struts! is that possible?

Comment: @KhashayarNapster Yes; I gave you three mechanisms by which to do so: create a mapping with the "method" attribute set, use the url tag and its "method" attribute, or create the dynamic method invocation URL manually using the "!" syntax.

Comment: Thanx very much for your time but can you give me some example? because I still dont get it :-s

Comment: @KhashayarNapster I don't know what you need an example of. How to make an image a link? How to set `window.location`? How to use [the `<s:url>` tag's method attribute](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/url.html)?

Comment: I really dont know! I dont get anything from your answer ! I want by clicking to call different methods or at least set some variables so i can get it in the struts with getters! but i dont know how to do any of them and I dont think that image or window location gonna help!

Comment: @KhashayarNapster Okay, I give up then. If you can't describe what you want, there's no way to help. You call a Struts 2 method by making a request. You make a request by clicking a link or by re-setting the current window's location. You provide parameters to an action by using request parameters. Good luck.

Comment: again Thanx for your time! when you're confused you cant describe well and still cant get the point without looking to actual code! Anyway thanx!

Comment: You didnt mention whether you want to return any result from those two actions or just do an update. I think @Dave has given a complete answer. Unless you dont clarify more about your requirement, its difficult to help